# What is the Default Sort for Error List in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

How does the Default Sort (when no sort options are selected) of the Error List work in Visual Studio 2017? I have it set to the Current Document and expected that it would sort by order of occurrence (i.e. line number) except that isn't always the case depending on what errors exist in the file. For example, simple type cast errors or use of unassigned variables showed up in order by line, but when I added an error by leaving out a `;` those errors preceded the other errors regardless of where they were in the file. This made me wonder how this list is sorted by default.

[image]

Comment: For example when I had just type cast and unassigned variable errors, those were listed by line. But then I removed a semi colon from a couple lines and those went to the top of the list with the others still sorted by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question to Microsoft and it turns out that the default sort does have a pattern to it. Here is what they had to say:

> The sort of Error List depends on the different compiler. The general code first according to lexical analysis, and then syntax analysis. Because missing semicolon belongs to a lexical error, so, it appears first. And, the type conversions and use of declared values are syntax analysis, it should appear after lexical analysis.

Comment: It makes sense. Everything that happens after the first lexical error in a file may not be a genuine error but may instead just be the result of whatever assumed state the compiler put itself into in order to allow the parse to continue. If the assumptions are wrong it may be viewing code from the wrong perspective.